# JSONのデータを取得してHTMLの要素に入れたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

data.jsonというJSONのデータを取得して、データ内に入っている名前、住所、仕事内容のデータをindex.htmlのHTML内のcontents--tableの中に挿入したいのですが、data.jsonのデータすら読み取る事に失敗してしまいます。どのようなコードを打てば実装できるでしょうか。script.jsの中にコードをうちます。（script.jsの中にはまだ何も入ってません。）

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contents contents--table">
<div class="table_title">テーブル</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

data.json

```
{
    "name":"名前",
    "address":"住所",
    "work":[
        "仕事内容1"
        ,"仕事内容2"
    ]

}
```

Comment: 現状はとりとめもない完成形を求められていて、Q&Aとして答えようがなくなっている気がします。質問の範囲をまずは「data.jsonのデータすら読み取る事に失敗してしまいます」に焦点を当てませんか？ 回答者に答えて欲しい内容を念頭に質問文を校正してください。

Comment: `html javascript json file to table`とかで検索したこんな記事が参考になるかも。[How To Load JSON file to a HTML Table? Using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29538002/9014308), [How to convert JSON data to a html table...](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-json-data-to-a-html-table-using-javascript-jquery/), [JSON files into HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32292246/9014308), [How to set up writing to html table...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69986736/9014308), [How to I parse a JSON file to display...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56163003/9014308)